# error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant int sem_init(sem_t *s,0,unsigned int val);

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread,const pthread_attr_t *attr,    void*(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);

void *thread(void *vargp); 
/* Global shared variable */
volatile long cnt = 0; /* Counter */
sem_t mutex;
int sem_init(sem_t *s,0,unsigned int val);
void P(sem_t *s);
void V(sem_t *s);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  long niters; 
  int i, nthreads;
  pthread_t tid[1000];

  niters = atoi(argv[1]);
  nthreads = atoi(argv[2]);
  for (i=0; i < nthreads; i++)
  {
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread, &niters);
    printf("THREAD %d with tid= %ld CREATED \n", i, tid[i]);
  }
  for (i=0; i < nthreads; i++)
  {
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    printf("THREAD %d with tid= %ld TERMINATED \n", i, tid[i]);
  }

  /* Check result */
  if (cnt != (nthreads * niters))
    printf("BOOM! cnt=%ld  ---  RACE CONDITION\n", cnt);
  else
    printf("OK cnt=%ld\n", cnt);

  printf("PRESS CTRL-C to terminate or CTRL-Z to suspend \n");
  pause();
  exit(0);
}

/* Thread routine */
void *thread(void *vargp) 
{                                         
   long i, niters =  *((long *)vargp);                                         
   for (i = 0; i < niters; i++)
   {
     P(&mutex);
     cnt++;  
     V(&mutex);                 
   }                                             
   return NULL; 
}
```

I want to synchronize threads using semaphores, but when I declare the `sem_init()` function and make the middle argument 0, it gives me an error. Maybe the function is wrong. I also included the `semaphore.h` header.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "make middle argument 0"? It expects a type, not a value.

Comment: but when I make it like "int i" it does not working also

Comment: That line shouldn't even be there. you don't "make middle argument zero" on the prototype declaration; you do it in the *invoke*, which you're already doing in `main` with `sem_init(&mutex,0,1);`. So what prompted you to add that prototype in the first place (as well as the prototype for `pthread_create`) rather than include the proper system headers?

Comment: Fix your indentation first!